# Favourite questions and answers from 4th quarter of 2018

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

Happy New Year! I hope everyone enjoyed the holidays and the Winterbash.

Continuing the tradition, we would again ask the community to **link your favorite questions and answers created from 1st October 2018 to 31st December 2018.**

You can search all the eligible [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2018-10..2018-12) and [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2018-10..2018-12) posted the past quarter. Since we got 665 questions and ~1k answers in the past quarter (number of answers increased), to make your job easier, here are some data queries.

- [Questions with the most number of votes from the last quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738289/questions-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/10/01)
- [Questions with the most number of views from the last quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738288/questions-with-most-views-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/10/01)
- [Answers with the most number of votes from the last quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738290/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2018/10/01)

The above questions and answers are only for your assistance. Feel free to mention any question or answer you enjoyed writing. Since this is not a competition, there's no need to mention one question or answer per one answer. Also don't hesitate to mention our own questions and answers which you think didn't get the appreciation they deserved.

Answer (score 4):

## Answers:

Napoleon Wilson posted some awesome answers this quarter. One of them was an [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/93881/48608) to question [How to interpret Mac's dance in "It's Always Sunny..."?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/93777/48608)

I also liked a Q&A pair. The question [Why was Gasoline still the major source of fuel in Mad Max: Fury Road?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/94211/48608) from war_Hero and its [accepted answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/94215/48608) from Napoleon Wilson.

*Now starting to beating my own drums*

I enjoyed writing [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/94447/48608) to Ankit Sharma's question [What are all the Shakespearean themes in Gargoyles?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/94429/48608). Though the answer is adapted from Wiki, I searched about William Shakespeare's plays and came to know about characters.

I posted an [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/93192/48608) explaining the significance of title *Rangasthalam* to my own question [What is the significance of the title "Rangasthalam"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/93187/48608). The question didn't work out pretty well (perhaps I knew the answer at the time of posting the question) but answer gave me satisfaction.

Answer (score 2):

This self-answered question: [Could "Wreck-It Ralph" exist as a movie within the canon of Ralph Breaks the Internet?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/94534/could-wreck-it-ralph-exist-as-a-movie-within-the-canon-of-ralph-breaks-the-int) by MikeQ is probably my favourite in the timeframe you are asking about.

I love an Inception-esk type theory and it brings me no end of joy to try and prove how it could work and to overthink the ramifications it can have. To have this opportunity in a movie series I love... well, it was like Christmas had came early! Especially given that MikeQ himself had posted an answer with an opposing view to mine, it was almost like I was being invited to over indulge!

Answer (score 2):

## Questions.

- [How is the “bullets whizzing through water” effect created?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96099/how-is-the-bullets-whizzing-through-water-effect-created)
   This was a really interesting question that i hadn't thought about before, but it was fun to find out the answer!
- [How did Barry Keep up with his special diet in jail?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89891/how-did-barry-keep-up-with-his-special-diet-in-jail) This is (one of) my favorite question that I've asked and would love some new answers! (I know this wasn't from the fourth quarter but it hasn't been mentioned previously in one of these, so i figured it should count)

## Answers.

- [How is the "bullets whizzing through water" effect created?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96099/how-is-the-bullets-whizzing-through-water-effect-created) This was one of my favorite questions to answer and i feel I gave a concise, and accurate answer.
- [What did Cameron see in the Painting?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96003/what-did-cameron-see-in-the-painting) Now this is probably my overall favorite post, because of the interesting layers it adds to Camerons backstory.

Answer (score 2):

One of my favorite ANSWER's to one of my own questions by Walt was, [Does this pin Claudia wears have any significance?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/94136/does-this-pin-claudia-wears-have-any-significance).

And I too love the Q & A pair for, [What are all the Shakespearean themes in Gargoyles?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/94429/what-are-all-the-shakespearean-themes-in-gargoyles) from Ankit Sharma & Napoleon Wilson respectively! (Love thematic and reference questions, in case you couldn't tell!)

Answer (score -1):

Ever since I watched Infinity War, I didn't understand this.

[Why didn't Loki use the Tesseract?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/94532/why-didnt-loki-use-the-tesseract)